# Problema con el formato fecha con JasperReport en Java Swing

Tags: mysql, java-swing, jasper-reports

Tengo un problema con el plugin de JasperReport, estoy intentando mostrar o mejor dicho armar un PDF segun un filtro dado ("parametro") por fecha, el punto es que como todos deben saber MySql maneja el formato americano yyyy/MM/dd por lo que cuando le envio el parametro desde Java hacia JasperReport resulta ser incompatible porque por defecto JasperReport tiene este formato de fecha d/M/y  asi que genera inconvenientes, yo quisiera saber como puedo cambiar el formato del JasperReport para que sea igual que MySql y por lo tanto ya no tenga problemas al enviarselo desde java.
por favor no confundir campos con parametros. Adjunto una imagen donde muestra desde el Report el formato. Trate de ponerle el formato en el default value pero no funciono.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como pueden apreciar en la primer imagen establesco un parametro de tipo date, y en la segunda imagen cuando hago una prueba, me muestra el formato que maneja el cual producira un error porque no es el formato americano.
Agradesco de ante mano las personas que se tomen el tiempo de leer.